# Несколько вопросов по select

Tags: angularjs

```
<span ng-switch-when="rem" ng-show="dtek">
   <select class="rem" name="rem" id="rem" ng-change="bindService(remActive)" ng-model="remActive">
       <option value="" ng-show="!remActive" class="choose-rem">{{ 'ACTIONS.CHOOSE_REM' | translate }}</option>
       <option ng-repeat="service in services" ng-value="service.id" ng-init="remActive">{{service.name}}</option>
   </select>
   {{remActive|json}}
</span>
```

```
$scope.bindService = function (id) {
    $scope.remActive = Number(id);
};
```

1. Мне кажется, что я не верно делаю обновление `$scope.remActive`. По идее же должно оно обновляться не через функцию, а просто средством ngModel. Но у меня не получилось иначе. Объясните что не так.
2. Почему значение select переводит в строку?

В данный селект прилетает с сервера массив с объектами, там из нужного мне беру название(строка) и айди(инт).

Так же с сервера приходит айди элемента который юзер выбирал ранее. Если такой был.

Проблема в том что при перезагрузке страницы активные элемент не выводится если он не стинг. в контроллере все перевожу в стринг и консоль лог отстреливает верно. А джейсон в шаблоне только первый элемент показывает верно который пришел изначально с сервера как инт. А далее все следующиее когда пользователь клацает, показывает как строку (разницу видно так 1234 и "1234")

Почему это для меня проблема. Сначала пользователь авторизировался все гуд. Стоит активный его пункт, он может менять локализацию и все будет норм, погрузятся новые варианты на новом языке и будет активным тот же что и нужно. НО, если пользователь зашел, хочет сменить на другой пунк из списка(выбрал новый), и сменил язык, на сервер оно сразу не уходит, то, получаем белое поле селекта, пустое. Но при этом джейсон выводит нужый айди в виде строки.

Я так понимаю что сам селект переводит значения в строку. В контроллере все возможное я оборачивал и `Number()` и `parseInt()`

Простите много текста.

Вариант через ng-option

```
<select class="rem" name="rem" ng-model="remActive" ng-value="service.id" ng-options="service.id as service.name for service in services"></select>
```

не передает в контроллер вообще изменений.

контроллер

```
$scope.remActive = null;

$scope.$watch($scope.remActive, console.log('$scope.remActive',$scope.remActive));
```

если контроллер сделать так

```
$scope.bindService = function (id) {
        $scope.remActive = Number(id);
    };
```

а в шаблоне ngChange через фукнцию передать то передает. Но при смене языка теперь даже если было фиксированное(с сервера) значение как и раньше пусто еще и  json null выдает.

Comment: [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: пробовал. с ним у меня вообще не получилось.

Comment: не передавало значение выбраного пункта

Comment: добавляй пример как пробовал и что не получилось :-)

Comment: о. помоему сейчас получится) ща попробую. а то я больной тогда валялся. нужно было срочно. не получалось, плюнул сделал так. сейчас. поколупаю

Comment: если получится, добавляй свой собственный ответ с описанием решения

Comment: буду продолжать утром на свежую голову

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62188/discussion-between-grundy-and-maxim).

Answer (score 0):

Нормальное решение это ng-option

Вот так:

контроллер

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.services = [{id:1, name:'name1'},{id:2, name:'name2'},{id:3, name:'name3'}];//массив данных для списка
  $scope.remActive = 2;//активный пункт по умолчанию

  $scope.action = function(){
    console.log('rem', $scope.remActive)    
  }
});
```

Шаблон

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
         <span>
             <select ng-options="service.id as service.name for service in services" ng-model="remActive" class="rem" name="rem"></select>
              {{remActive|json}}
          </span>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" ng-click="action()">click</button>
  </body>
```

Но у меня по непонятной причине при выбора со списка новое значение не передается в контроллер. 
Помогло такое решение.

Изменения в шаблоне

```
<span>
  <select ng-options="service.id as service.name for service in services" ng-model="remActive" ng-change="bindRem(remActive)" class="rem" name="rem"></select>
  {{remActive|json}}
</span>
```

Изменения в контроллере

```
$scope.bindRem = function (id) {
    $scope.remActive = id;
};
```

Такая манипуляция с ngChange спасла. Все работает на отлично! 
Спасибо Grundy за помощь!

Comment: Это не решение, это какой то костыль непонятный. Поймите, если бы ``remActive`` не устанавливался с помощью ``select``, то результатом выполнения вашей функции всегда было бы ``remActive = 2``. Раз, как вы говорите манипуляция вам помогает, то это значит что переменная ``remActive`` устанавливается, но Вы косячите в проверке вашего значения. Если есть возможность, соберите пример на ``planker'е`` и давайте всё таки разберёмся что происходит.

Comment: собирал. все работает. проблема в том что в планкере собираю простой вараинт. в рабочем же варианте много моментом и нюансов, вполне возможно что где то ng-if за пределы скоупа. или еще что.

Comment: Это лишний раз доказывает, что у Вас осталась проблема в коде и приведённое решение, не является решением.